# Object is continuously spawning prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the Unity Engine to make a 2D game... to give you an idea of what it looks like, there is a generic space background, 4 rocks bouncing around the screen, and a tie fighter. My goal was to make the tie fighter explode (Which I did succeed in doing), destroy itself, and have a prefab take its place. I am new to c#, so I don't know much of the API. I tried using the second script to destroy the tie fighter, then instantiate a prefab... Now, whenever I run the game, it spawns enough clones to the point where Unity crashes and I do not know how to fix it. I tried googling stuff and doing a manual fix (hence the bools), but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, please don't just comment; write it as an answer so that I can mark it correct if it works. Here are the scripts (I am assuming the error is in the second one, but I included both for reference):

First Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class tfScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

Vector3 tfPos;
Vector3 worldPos;
float mousePosInBlocksx;
float mousePosInBlocksy;
int lives;
public Sprite tieFight; // Drag your first sprite here
public Sprite kaboom; // Drag your second sprite here
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
float makeThingsGoBoom;

// Use this for initialization
public void Start () 
{
    tfPos = new Vector3 (3f, 3f, -4f);
    lives = 20;
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); // we are accessing the SpriteRenderer that is attached to the Gameobject

    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null) // if the sprite on spriteRenderer is null then
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = tieFight; // set the sprite to sprite1
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update () 
{
    GameObject controller = GameObject.Find ("controller");
    gameController gameCon = controller.GetComponent<gameController> ();

    mousePosInBlocksx = ((Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width) * 16);
    mousePosInBlocksy = ((Input.mousePosition.y / Screen.width) * 12)+2;

    tfPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (mousePosInBlocksx, .5f, 15.5f);
    tfPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (mousePosInBlocksy, .5f, 11.5f);

    this.transform.position = tfPos;
    if (makeThingsGoBoom == 0) 
    {   
        gameCon.Update();
    }

}

public void ChangeTheDarnSprite ()
{

    if (spriteRenderer.sprite == tieFight) { // if the spriteRenderer sprite = sprite1 then change to sprite2
        spriteRenderer.sprite = kaboom;
    } 
    else 
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = tieFight;
    }
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.name.Contains("spacerock")  ) 
    {
        lives--;
        print (getLives ());

    }

    if (collider.gameObject.name.Contains("spacerock")) // If the space bar is pushed down
    {

        spriteRenderer.sprite = kaboom;
        makeThingsGoBoom = 0;
    }
}

public void increaseLives()
{
    lives++;
}

public double getLives()
{
    return lives;
}


}
```

Second Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
public GameObject tf;
public GameObject tfpf;
public bool iBlowedUp = false;

public void Start()
{

}

public void Update () 
{
    boom ();
}

public void boom()
{
        iBlowedUp = true;

        if (iBlowedUp = true) 
        {
            StartCoroutine (waitForIt ());
            Destroy (tf);
            tfpf = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/tfpf")) as GameObject;
            iBlowedUp = false;
        }
}

public IEnumerator waitForIt()
{
    print ("Bob lives #2!");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1); 
    print ("John is a turtle #2!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling following method in a `Update` function which is executed constantly.

```
public void boom()
{
        iBlowedUp = true;

        if (iBlowedUp = true) 
        {
            StartCoroutine (waitForIt ());
            Destroy (tf);
            tfpf = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/tfpf")) as GameObject;
            iBlowedUp = false;
        }
}
```

An if `iBlowedUp = true; if (iBlowedUp = true){` doesn't make sense, because the statement is true always.

It should be similar to:

```
public void boom()
{
        if (iBlowedUp == true) 
        {
            iBlowedUp = false;
            StartCoroutine (waitForIt ());
            Destroy (tf);
            tfpf = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/tfpf")) as GameObject;
        }
}
```

Probably you want to set `iBlowedUp` to `true` somewhere else. As I consider in a `tfScript.Update()` method, instead of calling `Update` method.

```
if (makeThingsGoBoom == 0) 
{   
    gameCon.iBlowedUp = true;
    //gameCon.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (iBlowedUp = true) 
        {
            iBlowedUp = false;
            StartCoroutine (waitForIt ());
            Destroy (tf);
            tfpf = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/tfpf")) as GameObject;

        }
```

before instantiate make isBlowedUp false, I cant say ı understood well this "Unity crashes". there is some complexity in your code. I hope you fix them as well

Comment: What do you mean by decomposition?

Comment: You shouldn't use variable names something like tf, tfpf and instead of using resources.load method every time crate a GameObject at top call it something special and use instantiate method with that object. This way your code will run faster and  I don't know why you did this  gameCon.Update(); update method is already called everytime in a timelapse.

Comment: Like I said, I am very unfamiliar with c#. I just used tf for tiefighter, and tfpf for tiefighterprefab. I found the resources.load method online... and originally I was doing gameCon.boom(); but it was crashing as well. I just forgot to switch it back.